# What does the value NaN4505e-001 mean in Octave/matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

What does the value `NaN4505e-001` mean in Octave/matlab?

The full output line is `Iteration   250 | Cost:  NaN9784e-001`
The corresponding statement in the library function is  `fprintf('%s %4i | Cost: %4.6e\r', S, i, f1);`

So, my question is how can a `%4.6e` return this value `NaN4505e-001`?

Comment: Could you explain how you got this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely is the concatenation of three strings resulted from displaying a `NaN` and two floating point numbers. For example:

```
fprintf(1, '%d%d%.0e\n', NaN, 450, 0.5)
```

**Later edit**: Given the new information added to the original question, the most likely cause is `f1` variable being a 3-element vector of doubles, with the value `[NaN, 450, 0.5]`, or 2 element vector `[NaN, 450.5]`.

To see what exactly is the cause, I'd recommend adding a conditional breakpoint on the `fprintf` call with the condition `i == 250`, then inspecting the `f1` value.

*However, `i` and `j` are reserved by MATLAB for the complex square root of -1, so the condition might be never taken by the debugger. That's why is a bad idea to use those two identifiers as variable names.*

Comment: Agree. +1.  This is the most likely culprit.

Comment: I have clarified the question.. the value seems to result from a single %4.6e format instruction

Comment: @TG_ Added info to the answer.